# How to enable IMAP module

Tags: php, linux, debian, imap

I would like install imap on debian wheezy. I do this step

```
apt-get install php5-imap
```

And I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-imap is already the newest version.
```

So, this means IMAP is installed... OK, next I do

```
php5enmod imap
```

Next I type

```
php -m
```

And I got this error

What is wrong?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_imap.dll' - /usr/local/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Maybe a rights issue?

Comment: The `/usr/local` paths look like you are not using the system-installed libraries at all.

Comment: So, what I should to do? Because I newbie at Linux

Comment: Please rename the question more appropriately, since IMAP is a protocol not a package/implementation. I also think this question is more suited to serverfault than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer.

In my php.ini was

```
extension="imap.so"
```

But I installed imap to non-standard path, so I change this line to

```
extension="path/to/my/extension/imap.so"
```